# Type for array to contain at least x elements of certain type

Tags: typescript

```
type RequiredElements = {key: 'key_1'} | {key: 'key_2'}

const arr = [
  { key: "key_1" },
  { key: "key_2" },
];
```

Is there a way to write a type for the above array so it has to contain all the elements from the RequiredElements type?

This would fail (missing key_1):

```
const arr = [
  { key: "key_2" },
  { key: "key_3" },
];
```

This would fail (missing key_1):

```
const arr = [
  { key: "key_2" },
  { key: "key_2" },
  { key: "key_3" },
  { key: "key_4" },
  { key: "key_5" },
];
```

This would pass(Keys 1 and 2 are present):

```
const arr = [
  { key: "key_2" },
  { key: "key_3" },
  { key: "key_1" },
  { key: "key_5" },
  { key: "key_6" },
];
```

Comment: There is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way.  The type system is not really intended to capture "exhaustive lists" like this.  You could write a generic type that acts as a constraint and use it with a helper function like [this code](https://tsplay.dev/N7P2nm), but there are caveats and edge cases.  Does that approach work for your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you, that's impressive indeed but it, unfortunately, won't work for my scenario. I wanted to use this hypothetical type for React component prop so calling a function like this won't help. I think I'll just go with the runtime validation then.